# how to build a cluster of RocksDB nodes?

Tags: rocksdb

I am impressed by the RocksDB: the merge operation and its columnar storage. But I found that RocksDB runs on a single node. It is more like a library. In my use case, the size of KV doesn't fit in one node. So I need a "management system" which I call "control plane". The control plane manages a cluster of RocksDB nodes and presents the cluster as a big KV storage layer.

The control plane

- management membership of nodes and partition each node holds.
- detect node failures and recover.
- detect hot partition and split.

I could not find resources for building on top of RocksDB. It could be wonderful if there are open source projects out there. My team is not big enough to build on top of RocksDB on our own.

Comment: Here is list of users of RocksDB, some of them provide multi-node management and opensource:
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/USERS.md

Answer (score -3):

This is a poor quality question and will probably get closed.

But just to give you some direction - what you are asking for is the architecture of a distributed database.

You can start by combining raft with rocks and incrementally add the features required